# Unable to push json file to Heroku for database data dump

Tags: python, django, heroku

I'm working on a school project, I have no experience with any of this and am having a hard time with this last step of setting up a website. For some background, the front end is coded in Next.js, backend is Python utilizing Django, and I have deployed the backend to Heroku (I have the app built and the database (postgreSQL) setup). I have done all of this following a tutorial that I found on Udemy which is only about a year old.

I have run into some issues along the way but was able to figure them out after some trial and error, but this one is really giving me a hard time.

So, in the tutorial he does a datadump and puts it into a file named "dump.json", then he runs the following command: heroku run python manage.py loaddata dump.json, which dumps the data into Heroku and the database populates and his Heroku app is up and running (it's connected to the Django rest framework, which is coded in the front end). Well, here is what I get when I run the command, I have to specify the path to manage.py otherwise it won't work, fyi...
[image]

I have tried so many different ways to run this command..I have specified the path (both relative and the full path), I have moved the file to different locations in the directory and tried from there, but I always get the same error, saying the Fixture doesn't exist. Oh, and yes, I did "git add .  git commit -m 'changes' git push heroku master' after creating the json file. I have no clue what to do to fix this...

Here is the file structure of my project:
[image]

If I can provide anything else that could help you help me, please let me know. Thank you in advance

EDIT: Just to show that I've tried from the root directory also, even tried to re-push everything from there, but as you can see there is nothing new to push, so supposedly everything is in heroku already, but still getting the same error...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try running this from the root of the project directory. From your command line it looks like you are a few levels down in the file hierarchy.

`pwd` for present working directory. You want to be in `~/Projects/my_pizza_website/`

Comment: I've tried that also, I've tried it from just about every position in the directory :/

Comment: I would make sure your project is deployed properly and the build was successful. It doesn't seem like based on the information provided that the file exists inside the dyno. You can run `heroku run bash --app {your_app}` to see if the file is inside.